# How to access the mp4 link from a video

Tags: streaming, web

Anyway to access the link to the video file on a streaming site.
For example, from this site I am able to get a download link but not a link ending with .mp4:
http://www.masterani.me/anime/watch/775-byousoku-5-centimeter/1

I specifically need a link ending with .mp4

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know about getting the link, but Chrome lets you right click and "Save As" the video just fine. I didn't add this as an answer because I'm not sure if this would be an acceptable alternative or not.

Comment: This looks like spam to me.

Comment: If you start the video you can right click in the video and select "save video as" to get the mp4 file. Verified using Chrome browser.

Comment: NO. The webmaster will upload a file of their own choosing. If there is a video, it does't have to be .mp4, it could be any video type. Say I put wool socks in my drawer, you can't just tell me, "Hey, when I put my hand in, I want your wool socks to be actually silk socks". However, if you manage to get a video you can always transcode it to a different format that you want (mp4 for example); there are many software that do this.

Comment: Like I said. I already know how to download the file. What I am asking is if it is possible to from a download link that isn't ending with .mp4 make it to a link which does. Judging from these responses it looks like that isn't possible. Thank you for your time, I guess I will simply have to find another way around it.

Comment: In all sane environments it shouldn't matter how the URL "ends", the content-type as sent by the server to the requesting client matters and in addition some client software will look at the beginning of the data being sent to see if there is more to learn from that. If you *really* must have a URL ending in .mp4, then the only way would be to use a service that redirects requests, by 302 or 301, and allows you to specify the URL. Cf. Shortlink services. Ofc that doesn't solve the problem of the redirected to link expiring…

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @VladGavriuk I don't anymore. This was posted 2016.
I think back then I wanted to make an application to watch anime (or any media i guess) together by first downloading it from the site and then streaming it from your device to your friends or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome web browser offers a "Copy video address" context menu item on that page, if you right click on the video.

Please note, that the link you will get in return seems to contain an authentication token. This means, that most likely it will only work for you and only for a limited time.

Accessing the URL returns a file, the signalled file name happens to end in `.mp4`. So while the URL doesn't point to a file ending in `.mp4`, the file that eventually is downloaded from that URL does.

Please note that different sites will have different structures and will use different technologies. There is no universal answer to this question.